# Operaciones múltiples intentando hacer una calculadora

Tags: java, java-11

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio y estoy teniendo algunos problemas para hacer una operación combinada.

Este es mi primer intento de hacer el código donde sea capaz de hacer múltiples operaciones dobles pero con el mismo signo. Ejemplo `(33.5+6+2+2+44.5)`

> Este método funciona bien

```
if (!exitOrHelp(respuesta)) {
                if (respuesta.contains("+")) {
                    double solucion = 0;
                    String[] numeros = respuesta.split("\\+");

                    for (String a : numeros) {
                        solucion = solucion + Double.parseDouble(a);
                    }
                    System.out.println(solucion);
                    System.out.println("Introduzca otra operación");
                } else if (respuesta.contains("-")) {
                    double solucion = 0;
                    String[] numeros = respuesta.split("-");

                    for (String a : numeros) {
                        solucion = solucion - Double.parseDouble(a);
                    }
                    System.out.println(solucion);
                    System.out.println("Introduzca otra operación");

                } else if (respuesta.contains("*") || (respuesta.contains("x"))) {
                    double solucion = 1;
                    String[] numeros = respuesta.split("\\*");

                    for (String t : numeros) {
                        solucion = solucion * Double.parseDouble(t);
                    }
                    System.out.println(solucion);
                    System.out.println("Introduzca otra operación");
                } else if (respuesta.contains("/")) {
                    double solucion = 0;
                    String[] numeros = respuesta.split("/");
                    solucion = Double.parseDouble(numeros[0]) / Double.parseDouble(numeros[1]);

                    if (numeros.length > 2) {
                        for (int r = 2; r < numeros.length; r++) {
                            solucion = solucion / Double.parseDouble(numeros[r]);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(solucion);
                    System.out.println("Introduzca otra operación");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No introdujiste ninguno de estos operandos: '+,-,*,/'");
                }
            }
```

Esta es la segunda prueba en la que intento hacer operaciones combinadas.

> Este método sólo funciona para ints ya que el programa sólo toma el valor que está antes y sólo para números que sólo tienen un dígito. Ejemplo: `3*7/2/2+4`

```
double calc = 0;
        String scan = "3*7/2/2+4";
        int resta = scan.indexOf('/');
        
        while (resta > 0) {
            calc = Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta - 1, resta)) / Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta + 1, resta + 2));
            String new_scan = scan.substring(0, resta - 1) + (int) calc + scan.substring(resta + 2, scan.length());
            scan = new_scan;
            resta = scan.indexOf('/');
        }
        System.out.println("Scan 1: " + scan);
        int resta2 = scan.indexOf('*');
        while (resta2 > 0) {
            calc = Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta2 - 1, resta2)) * Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta2 + 1, resta2 + 2));
            String new_scan = scan.substring(0, resta2 - 1) + (int) calc + scan.substring(resta2 + 2, scan.length());
            scan = new_scan;
            resta2 = scan.indexOf('*');
        }
        System.out.println("Scan 2: " + scan);
        int resta3 = scan.indexOf('+');
        while (resta3 > 0) {
            calc = Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta3 - 1, resta3)) + Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta3 + 1, resta3 + 2));
            String new_scan = scan.substring(0, resta3 - 1) + (int) calc + scan.substring(resta3 + 2, scan.length());
            scan = new_scan;
            resta3 = scan.indexOf('+');
        }
        System.out.println("Scan 3: " + scan);
        int resta4 = scan.indexOf('-');
        while (resta4 > 0) {
            calc = Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta4 - 1, resta4)) - Double.parseDouble(scan.substring(resta4 + 1, resta4 + 2));
            String new_scan = scan.substring(0, resta4 - 1) + (int) calc + scan.substring(resta4 + 2, scan.length());
            scan = new_scan;
            resta4 = scan.indexOf('-');
        }
        System.out.println("Scan 4: " + scan);
```

Después de varias horas probando varios métodos, me he quedado sin ideas y por eso pido ayuda.

El objetivo final que busco es poder hacer operaciones múltiples de dobles, números negativos y 2 dígitos. Ejemplo: `-73,5*4+744/2+76-6`

Sé más o menos cómo tiene que ser la estructura, pero no he sido capaz de desarrollarla. Adjunto una [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQsLO.jpg) de cómo creo que quedaría.

Comment: You are at [es.so]. Please translate your question to Spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Listo. Gracias @MauricioContreras

Comment: No olvides traducir el título

Comment: Listo! Traducido jeje